# How to detect whether office installed or not & notify the user using wix?

Tags: wix

I'm using wix recently and I want to detect whether office is installed or not using wix & show a dialog if it's not.
 I wrote the below code and it doesn't show the dialog. 
Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" >
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="f91c0ad9-0bbd-446d-9869-74801966e922">       
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="Path"
            Variable="OfficeSearchResult"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot"
            />

    <InstallUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="OfficeWarningDlg" After="ExecuteAction">
        <![CDATA[(OfficeSearchResult == "")]]>
      </Show>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="OfficeWarningDlg" Width="284" Height="73" Title="QuickTime Note" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="ctrl_dialog" Type="Text" X="38" Y="8" Width="240" Height="40" TabSkip="no">
          <Text>Microsoft office is required.</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="114" Y="52" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"  Cancel="yes" Text="OK">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
      </Dialog>     
    </UI>  
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a `<Condition>` element which will show a small dialog (and abort the installation) if its condition is not met? Then you could axe the `UI`/`InstallUISequence` stuff in your example.

```
<Wix ...>
  <Product ...>
    <Package ... />

    <Property Id="OFFICEISINSTALLED">
      <RegistrySearch Id="OfficeRegistryRegKey"
        Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot" />
    </Property>

    <Condition Message="Microsoft office is required to install this product">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR OFFICEISINSTALLED]]>
    </Condition>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```